# Why is only some of the JSON data posting to the DOM rather than all of it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get JSON data to post to the DOM using `ng-repeat` with AngularJS. It works, but not for everything. Only random pieces of data are getting posted. I'm assuming the issue is with what I have in the `ng-repeat`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

You can see how some of the sections come out blank.
Here's what the data looks like when I log it to the console:

[image]

here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dogdatabase-d31f.restdb.io/rest/_jsapi.js"></script>
</head>

<div ng-app="app" style="margin:45px;" ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
<ul>
    <li class="list" style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat="dog in $ctrl.dogs"><strong>{{dog.breed}}</strong>
        <br>
        Description: <span ng-repeat="description in dog.description">{{description}}</span>
        <br>
        Size: <span ng-repeat="size in dog.size" style="color:blue;">{{size}}</span>
        <br>
        Lifespan: <span ng-repeat="lifespan in dog.lifespan" style="color:green;">{{lifespan}}</span>
        <br><br>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='dogapp.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the JS file:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('dogsService', function($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getDogs = function() {
      return $http.get('https://dogdatabase-d31f.restdb.io/rest/dogs', {headers: {
        'x-apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
      }).then(response => response.data);
    };
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function(dogsService) {
    var _this = this;
    this.dogs = [];
    dogsService.getDogs().then((data) => {
      _this.dogs = data;

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });
```

Comment: `Only random pieces of data are getting posted` we need more details about that. You mean that some element of the array is not showed or that some properties of the object are not? 
And can you give us more information about the object properties?
`<span ng-repeat="description in dog.description">` are `description`,`size` and `lifespan` arrays too?

Comment: Is dog.description array? why you are using `ng-repeat` on span? and also have you checked the data that comes from service? maybe there are missing properties.

Comment: I just added a another picture above of what happens when I log the data to the console. But yes, some elements aren't showing up. The description, size, and lifespan are properties in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work now

```
<li class="list" style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat="dog in $ctrl.dogs"><strong>{{dog.breed}}</strong>
    <br>
    Description: <span>{{dog.description}}</span>
    <br>
    Size: <span style="color:blue;">{{dog.size}}</span>
    <br>
    Lifespan: <span style="color:green;">{{dog.lifespan}}</span>
    <br><br>
</li>
```

Comment: removed ng-repeats